# About closed map

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Can someone help me to prove this equivalence :

let $f:E \rightarrow F$ we have

$1)$ for all $y\in F$ and for all open $U$ from $E$ such that  $f^{-1}(\{y\})\subset U$, there exists a neighborhood $V$ of $y$ such that $f^{-1}(V)\subset  U$.

2) $f$ is closed

I strated by $1) \Rightarrow 2)$ let $C$ closed from $E$ we want to prove that $f(C)$ is closed, as $C$ is closed $E\setminus C $ is open, but i don't know how to use $1)$

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For 1 implies 2: Show that the closure of $f(C)$ is $f(C)$ by taking a point $y$ not in $f(C)$ and applying 1) to this point. You want to show that $y\notin \overline{f(C)}$, which is equivalent to proving that there is a neigborhood $V$ of $y$ such that $V\subset F\backslash f(C)$. To find this $V$, use 1) with $U=E\backslash C$.

For the other direction: We have $f^{-1}(y)\subset U$. Thus $y\notin f(E\backslash U)$ which is closed by 2). Therefore, there exists a neighborhood $V$ of $y$ such that $V \subset F\backslash f(E\backslash U)$. I let you conclude from here.

Comment: yes please, for the first direction we take $y$ from $\overline{f(C)}$ and we suppose that $y\notin f(C)$ right ?

Comment: i find that $f(E\setminus C)\cap f(C)\neq \emptyset$  is this the contradiction ? please

Comment: I've edited my answer to give you more details.

Comment: why if we suppose that $x\notin A$ and we find that $x\notin B$ it means that $B\subset A$ ??

Comment: Because if $x \in B$ and $x \notin A$, then $x \notin B$.